# Report Optimization Issue

Tags: java, mysql, mongodb, report

I'am having 6 reports in my web application. All the reports using huge queries around 15 table joins and also query results looping again to do some calculations before present the report to user.

This take long time to load a report. I am using MySQL with Java

What is the best way to fix this issue?

1. If caching is good what are the available options for that?
2. I'am planing to create a table and insert all the required data to that table, then reports can access to that table, if it's possible what is the best way to load data to that table?
3. Can MongoDb or other NoSql DB fix this issue?
4. Or is there any standard way to do these kind of things?

Comment: If there is lot of data to query then I would go for the 2nd option. Also, note that this table where you will put the data to query should be denormalized in order to have faster results. More info: [Business Intelligence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_intelligence)

Comment: Step #1 with a slow SQL query is to **look at the execution plan**. The number of JOINs is not as significant how the JOIN is executed (i.e. hash/merge/loop) and the cardinality of the JOIN. (Indices are the first "optimization" feature in an SQL implementation.) Relational Algebra is a wonderful thing. And no, "No SQL" will not automatically "fix" this issue.

Comment: @Luiggi : yes you are correct data should be denormalized as much as possible, but my problem is how to update that table when update real table data ?

Comment: @pst : Yes with No SQL i'll have to do some work to fix this,my idea is only query optimization or indexing will not totally fix the issue, is it wrong ?

Comment: If you have fifteen way joins it is hard to imagine it is denormalized as possible. NoSQL database (and there are many flavours) tend to favour data *without* joins.  Is the data set so large that you cannot load it all into memory and do the joins there?

Comment: @Peter : good point ,yes data set can be too large to keep in memory, does that mean i can't use any caching client ? (like redis or memcache)

Comment: You may find that some tables are smaller than others.  You might gain by having the smaller tables in memory and leave the larger tables in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `Explain` in front of your query and figure out if your `Joins` are using any indexes. Hopefully you are usually joining your tables in a similar way, so if you add the right indexes, it should speed it up quite a bit.

For example, if you had,

```
Select carrots FROM veggies
JOIN fruits ON fruits.color = veggies.color
WHERE veggies.weight=.5
```

You would want to add an index to the `color` column in the `fruits` table, and an index to the `weight` column of the `veggies` table.

Comment: yes , it will speed up quite a bit, but here not only queries after the query there are some calculations to do with looping , i want a way to store pre-prepared report data, and update those data when real data updated.

Comment: Perhaps adding some example code (with queries) would help us understand :)

Comment: IF you are looping through the queries to do calculations then that is probably a performance killer. Please post the query and the explain statement if possible.

Comment: One query contain more thank 2500 characters, so i don't think it will be much easy to read and understand.